# Counter file placement and naming convention

Tags: naming, convention

Ok this one might be stupid, but i'm losing too much time overthinking a solution.

I have a web app with 2 differents kind of payment modules.
These modules need (each) a counter file, incremented each time someone want to pay, and locked while incrementing to make sure the payment get a unique payment reference.

The files were placed inside the main directory (public_html) and have been overriden by a bad versionning move.

So I want to move them outside of public_html, where I already placed the main config file.
But having these critical file placed at the root of my ftp sounds stupind and dangerous. So I'll create a **directory** to place them.

This is a lot of text just to ask this :

How would you call this **directory** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, your question has not related especially with PHP, it's a common issue. You can use of one of standard directories to share data between the applications.

### `/var`

From the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (FHS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard):

> `/var` contains variable data files. This includes spool directories and files, administrative and logging data, and transient and temporary files. 
>   ([read more](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#THEVARHIERARCHY))

Some options:

- You can store your file directly in the `/var`.
- Also `/var/tmp` can hold temporary files for a longer time and doesn't clean it after reboot (depends on your system).
- Or you can create a custom subdirectory in the `/var/opt` with name that relevant to your applications.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, var is a good idea (but I won't use the one at the root, just needed a name :)